# Problem disable fields of a select in html with JS

Tags: javascript, html, select

I try to disable a field when an option is chosen in a select. I have created a script with a function in JS to disable it, more however it does not work. Any ideas what to do? When I select "T in% compared to the previous day", I need the "Time /%" field to be disabled, which I have not achieved.

So the code I have implemented for the select is this

Here I create the selectable menu with the fields that they will have and then through a script I pass it to fill the fields and I also create the function to disable the "Hours" boxes. So, here the problem arises, inside the script when const select = document.querySelector (# 'TipoPatron2') is started The table disappears, more however when the query selector is commented the table is still there

```html
<table border="0">

  <body>
    <td><strong>Patrón 2</strong>(
      <select name="TipoPatron2" id="TipoPatron2">
        <option value="00">T desde el encendido</option>
        <option value="01" selected="selected">T desde las 12:00</option>
        <option value="10">T en % respecto día anterior</option>
      </select>)</td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="changeP2();" value="Actualizar"> <label id="Error2" style="color: red"></label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr color="#ccff00">
              <td>Cambio</td>
              <td>Hora/%</td>
              <td>Minutos</td>
              <td>Dimado</td>
              <td>Dimado Entrada</td>
              <td>Color</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="mytbody2">
          </tbody>



          <script language="javascript">
            let tbody2 = document.querySelector("#mytbody2");
            var I = 1;
            for (I = 1; I <= 8; I++) {
              document.writeln("<tr align=center>");
              document.writeln("<td>" + I + " <input type=\"checkbox\" checked id=\"AP2C" + I + "\"></td>");
              document.writeln("<td><input type=\"text\" onpaste = \"alerta()\" value=\"0\" id=\"HP2C" + I + "\" maxlength=3 size=3></td>");
              document.writeln("<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" id=\"MP2C" + I + "\" maxlength=2 size=2></td>");
              document.writeln("<td><select name=\"dimado\" id=\"DP2C" + I + "\"><option value =\"0\">0%</option><option value =\"1\">1%</option><option value =\"2\">2%</option><option value =\"3\">3%</option><option value =\"4\">4%</option><option value =\"5\">5%</option><option value =\"6\">6%</option><option value =\"7\">7%</option><option value =\"8\">8%</option><option value =\"9\">9%</option><option value=\"10\">10%</option><option value=\"11\">11%</option><option value=\"12\">12%</option><option value=\"13\">13%</option><option value=\"14\">14%</option><option value = \"15\">15%</option><option value=\"16\">16%</option><option value=\"17\">17%</option><option value=\"18\">18%</option><option value=\"19\">19%</option><option value = \"20\">20%</option><option value=\"21\">21%</option><option value=\"10\">10%</option><option value = \"22\">22%</option><option value = \"23\">23%</option><option value = \"24\">24%</option><option value = \"25\">25%</option><option value = \"26\">26%</option><option value = \"27\">27%</option><option value = \"28\">28%</option><option value = \"29\">29%</option><option value = \"30\">30%</option><option value = \"31\">100%</option></select></td>");
              document.writeln("<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" id=\"IP2C" + I + "\" maxlength=2 size=2></td>");
              document.writeln("<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" id=\"CP2C" + I + "\" maxlength=2 size=2></td>");
              document.writeln("</tr>");
            }
            //Creo una selector para que valide si se selecciona la opción de "T%" se ejecute la función desactivar
            /*const select = document.querySelector('#TipoPatron2')
                select.onchange = () => {
                    if (select.value == '10') {
                        desact()
                    }
                }
            */
            //Se crea la función alerta para cuando se haga un pegado en los box se ejecute la alerta
            function alerta() {
              alert("Seguro que quieres actualizar?");
            }
            //Se crea una función desactivar que se efectua en un for de 0 a 8 con el ID de las horas 
            function desact() {
              for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
                document.getElementById('HP2C' + i).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            }
          </script>
          <tr align="center">
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </body>
  </td>
```

Photos when when queryselector is not commented
[image]

Now, I go to the page and the table disappears enter image description here
[image]

And if I comment the const select = document.querySelector ('# TipoPatron2') the table appears enter image description here
[image]

[image]

I need this query selector, since this is in charge of disabling the "Hora/%" when "T en % respecto día anterior" is selected in the first select. Any ideas what to do pls?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have `<body>`  where I would expect a `tbody` and no `tr` before the first td.

Comment: @mplungjan you're right, thanks but, the options have not been disabled yet.
Also, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this

1. I made the creation of the select simpler
2. I assume you mean to disable the HP2Cs when TipoPatron2 have value "10"

```js
const tbody2 = document.getElementById("mytbody2");
tbody2.innerHTML = Array.from({length: 8}, (_, index) => index + 1).map(i => `<tr align=center>
  <td>${i}<input type="checkbox" checked id="AP2C${i}" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="0" id="HP2C${i}" maxlength=3 size=3 /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="0" id="MP2C${i}" maxlength=2 size=2 /></td>
  <td><select name="dimado" id="DP2C ${i}">${Array.from({length: 29}, (_, index) => index + 1).map(i => `<option value="${i}">${i}%</option>`).join("") }
    <option value = "31">100%</option></select></td>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="IP2C${i}" maxlength=2 size=2 /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="0" id="CP2C${i}" maxlength=2 size=2 /></td>
  </tr>`).join("")

const HP2Cs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=HP2C]")
document.getElementById("TipoPatron2").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const dis = this.value==="10"; 
  HP2Cs.forEach(hp2c => hp2c.disabled = dis)
})    
tbody2.addEventListener("paste", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id.startsWith("HP2C")) alert("Seguro que quieres actualizar?");
})
```

```html
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Patrón 2</strong>(
        <select name="TipoPatron2" id="TipoPatron2">
          <option value="00">T desde el encendido</option>
          <option value="01" selected="selected">T desde las 12:00</option>
          <option value="10">T en % respecto día anterior</option>
        </select>)</td>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="changeP2();" value="Actualizar"> <label id="Error2" style="color: red"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr color="#ccff00">
              <td>Cambio</td>
              <td>Hora/%</td>
              <td>Minutos</td>
              <td>Dimado</td>
              <td>Dimado Entrada</td>
              <td>Color</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="mytbody2">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: U save my life, seriously